# Making Typeclass Instance with `implicit def`?

Tags: scala, typeclass

Given:

```
scala> trait Resource[A] { def f: String }
defined trait Resource

scala> case class Foo(x: String)
defined class Foo
```

And then an implicit:

```
scala> implicit def fooToResource(foo: Foo): Resource[Foo] = 
        new Resource[Foo] { def f = foo.x }
```

The following works:

```
scala> implicitly[Resource[Foo]](Foo("foo")).f
res2: String = foo
```

I defined a function:

```
scala> def f[A](x: A)(implicit ev: Resource[A]): String = ev.f
f: [A](x: A)(implicit ev: Resource[A])String
```

However, the following code fails to compile:

```
scala> f(Foo("foo"))
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Resource[Foo]
       f(Foo("foo"))
```

Secondly, then I tried:

```
scala> f2(Foo("bippy"))
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Resource[Foo]
       f2(Foo("bippy"))
        ^
```

Lastly, I attempted:

```
scala> def g(foo: Foo)(implicit ev: Resource[Foo]): String = ev.f
g: (foo: Foo)(implicit ev: Resource[Foo])String

scala> g(Foo("5"))
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Resource[Foo]
       g(Foo("5"))
        ^
```

However, it failed too. How can I fix `f`?

Answer (score 5):

Ok with Peter Neyens' answer, this is not a typeclass, this is an implicit conversion, which you should avoid - there should have been some warning, asking that you import scala.language.implicitConversions.

As a complement, here is why the first `implicitly` works:

Implicitly is just:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit ev: T): T = e
```

When you write `implicitly[T]` *without supplying a parameter*, it will look for an implicit of type `T` in scope and return it. However, you call implicitly with a parameter (I believe there is no legitimate reason to do that, ever), so it would just return your parameter, `Foo("foo")`, an instance of `Foo`. Except that you explicitly stated that `T` should be  Resource[Foo]. If you had written a type ascription, such as `(Foo("foo"): Resource[Foo])`, it would have worked the same way. `implicitly` is not relevant here.

The point is that `Foo("foo")` is not of the expected type `Resource[Foo]`, but just a `Foo`. The compiler would reject that, except that at this point, the implicit conversion you defined above kicks in, and your `Foo` instance is transformed into a `Resource[Foo]`. Then, you can call `f`.

Next, you call your `f(Foo("foo"))`. There is an implicit parameter, however this time, you don't supply it. So the compiler looks for one (while it did no such thing the first time), and as there is no such instance, fails.

Comment: This extra information about `implicitly` is indeed a nice complement to my answer, thanks @Didier Dupont.

Comment: Thanks. It made no sense to me at first, so I thought it might be worth sharing

Comment: `I believe there is no legitimate reason to do that, ever` No reason to do what? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @KevinMeredith No reason to call `implicitly` with an explicit parameter, as in `implicitly[Resource[Foo]](Foo("foo"))`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - what about the following pseudocode spray-json example: `JSON -> String`? `def jsonToString[A : RootJsonFormat](x: A): String = implicitly[RootJsonFormat[A]].write(x).toString`? That's not idiomatic?

Comment: @KevinMeredith This code is all right, and no `(value)` parameter is passed to `implicitly` in this code — the `[type]` parameter  is all right, it is the point of implicitly. Here `implicitly` is called without a parameter, then the `write` method is called on the result. Passing a parameter to `implicitly` defeats its purpose : using the implicit system to fill  the parameter with the implicit value, then returning it.

Answer (score 4):

The `implicit def fooToResource` is not a type class instance, but does return one if you supply a `Foo`, that's the reason the following line works :

```
implicitly[Resource[Foo]](Foo("foo")).f
```

A solution would be to change the `Resource.f` function to take a parameter of type `A` :

```
trait Resource[A] { 
  def f(a: A): String 
}
```

You then could define a `Resource` type class instance for `Foo` as follows:

```
case class Foo(x: String)

implicit val fooResource = new Resource[Foo] {
  def f(foo: Foo) = foo.x
}
```

We can rewrite `f` to use the changed `Resource` :

```
def f[A](a: A)(implicit resA: Resource[A]): String = resA.f(a)
```

Which does what (I think) you need :

```
f(Foo("hello world")) // String = hello world
```